# "Be late (by/for)..." - "Be...late"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

Could you possibly let me know which structure is the proper way to convey "being late"?

> - My apologizes mr. Manson! But I guess I............. 
>   **a.** will be late **for** 10 minutes. 
>   **b.** will be late **by** 10 minutes. 
>   c. will be **10 minutes late**.

I have always stumbled on ether constructions 'b' and 'c', but I've got no clue if 'a' is wrong and if it is, then why?

Please let me know about it.

Comment: a. is wrong, because it isn't said that way. "My apologize" is not correct.

Comment: I meant "my apologie**s**" Jack. That was a typo. Thank you for correcting me. I edited the thread.

Comment: A minor mistake, it should be 'Mr. Manson.' Capitalize the title.

Comment: Thank you very much DG. :) Point taken. +1 for your punctuality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) This is incorrect. This would mean you are going to be late until 10 minutes has passed and then you will stop being late. This doesn't really make sense.

B) This is fine. It is gramatically correct but it sounds a bit unnatural. It sounds better in colloquial speech if you are a bit unsure and add 'about'. "I will be late by about 10 minutes".

C) This is good. It is gramatically correct and sounds good. If you are unsure which to use, pick this one.

Some other notes:

"My apologize Mr. Manson" is incorrect. It should be "My apologies, Mr. Manson". Using apologies as a plural noun instead of apologize as a verb. Alternatively, to use 'apologize' here you could say: "I apologize, Mr. Manson"

"I guess I..." is strange here. "My apologies, Mr. Manson, but I will be 10 minutes late" is clearer and more concise.